# Spring Web MVC localization display Japanese error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring MVC Web application for demo localization feature.
[image]

**WelcomeController.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
    public ModelAndView user() {
        return new ModelAndView("welcome");
    }

}
```

**messages_en_US.properties**

```
hello=Hello
```

**messages_vi_VN.properties**

```
hello=Xin chào
```

**message_ja_JP.properties**

```
hello=こんにちは
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Internatinalization</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
Language: <a href="?lang=en_US">English</a> - <a href="?lang=vi_VN">Viet Nam</a> - <a href="?lang=ja_JP">日本語</a>
<h2>
    <spring:message code="welcome"/>
</h2>
Locale: ${pageContext.response.locale}
</body>

</html>
```

**springmvc-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>
    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.mvc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<% response.sendRedirect("welcome.mvc"); %>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error:
[image]

How to fix the above error?

Comment: もしもし Doovy - see BalusC's site http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Answer (score 1):

I use own text editor (for example: Notepad++) then save properties files in UTF-8 encoding

[image]

[image]